# How is AttributeUsageAtribute implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I have a 2 part question.

First, as the title says, does anybody know how AttributeUsageAtribute is implemented? It can only be applied to a class that derives from Attribute and if not, it will error out with:
Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute

Second, can I write a similar Attribute that can be applied to classes that derive from a specific class or implement a specific interface?

Comment: I think that's just hardcoded C# compiler magic.

Comment: It's also VB.Net compiler magic, but the same point stands - you *can* construct .NET code directly using ILASM that breaks the constraints. And, to the second question, no.

Comment: There are very few attributes that the compile is aware of. `AttributeUsage` is one of them, as is `Obsolete`.

Comment: I analysed  AttributeUsageAttribute with Reflector. There is no code in it which produces this error, which seems logical, since this error is shown at compile time and not at runtime.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: The question is about how AttributeUsageAtribute is implemented and now how it is used.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer and the link doesn't answer my question either. Thanks for responding though. I appreciate it since even though it doesn't answer the question, I learned something new as I didn't know about attribute targets.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: Would you answer by showing me how to declare and use a hash table if my question was "How is Hashtable implemented"? Seriously ... I really don't want to be arguing about semantics. It appears that you are the only one that doesn't understand my question so why change it since I already explained what I meant by it. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @Rado: We'll have to agree to disagree. By the looks of it, your quetsion had nothing to do with `AttributeUsage`, but rather limiting the scope of an attribute. Accepting the other answers kind of proves that. `AttributeUsage` is strictly for members, `class`, `method`, `constructor`, etc. It doesn't seem like that's what you were after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) this is compiler specific

2)you can try the following trick:

```
var attributes = typeof(A).GetCustomAttributes(A.GetDerivedFromAOnlyAttributeType(), false);
// using an attribute outside the A class

class A {
    protected class DerivedFromAOnlyAttribute : Attribute { }
    public static Type GetDerivedFromAOnlyAttributeType() {
        return typeof(DerivedFromAOnlyAttribute);
    }
}
[A.DerivedFromAOnly] //ok
class B : A {
}
[A.DerivedFromAOnly] //error
class C { 
}
```

Comment: He's asking about "a similar Attribute that can be applied to classes that derive from a specific class"?

Comment: @JamesJohnson - Have you actually *read* the question? He's asking how that attribute is tied to classes that derive from `Attribute`, and whether he can implement a similar structure.

Comment: The second question target is how to implement the Attribute 'DerivedFromAOnly' only valid on classes derived from A, like an Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute. Rado???

Comment: @James Johnson: Anyway, I have not downvoted you. I think your answer shouldn't be downwoted.<br>
Rado: Where are you?? Please correct the subject...

Comment: @DimitryG: Thanks, if there's no better answer for #2, I'll mark it as the answer. Btw ... why should I change the subject. I am interested how AtributeUsage is implement and not how to use it, which I know, and that is what James Johnson's response is about.Btw, your answer of #2 wouldn't work for me since I want to also use the attribute outside the class (as in find classes with that attribute)

Comment: @JamesJohnson - does your answer (or link) explain how to implement an attribute that can only be applied to classes that derive from a certain base class? Because that's what the OPs question boils down to...

Comment: @Rado: I have improved my code to allow using this attribute outside the class.